# Style wp_page_menu() items

Tags: php, menus, navigation

I'm new to developing a custom template in Wordpress but I fail to see how I can style a menu item seperately.

With `posts` I can loop through them and place them in custom html elements. With `wp_page_menu()` I can only output the whole list. How can I loop through each item and place them in my custom template?

**Html Template:**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right is-hidden">
  <li>
   <a class="page-link" href=""> ... </a>
  </li>
  ...
  ...
</ul>
```

Comment: by your comment I understand you want to show navigation in your own way,,,,,rather than using default output of wordpress is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: can you please share the html template of yours, using for navigation...

Comment: I've edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below the function for showing navigation menu. 
Here, `$menu` is equivalent to ***Menu name, ID, or slug***

```
<?php 
function showMyMenu($menu)
{
    $navData = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu); 
?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right is-hidden">
    <?php
    foreach($navData as $k => $v)
    {   
        echo '<li><a class="page-link" href="' . $v->url . '"> ' . $v->title . ' </a></li>';
    }
    ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It's my pleasure, :)

Answer (score 1):

Following the code of the `wp_page_menu` directs me to the function [`get_pages`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages). This is probably what you are looking for.

Looking at the function calls in [`wp_page_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_page_menu/) and [`wp_list_pages`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/), you'll get an idea about what arguments you should pass to the `get_pages` function.